# SSH hangs on login after 'last update'

Tags: ssh, login

I'm having a bit of trouble. My SSH connection hangs for about 10 seconds when logging in. I've tried disabling the system info MOTD and a number of other things but it just doesn't seem to work. Trying `ssh user@host -vvv` doesn't help either as the log ends before the hang. It just says:

`Last login: Wed Apr 17 12:52:04 2013 from 194.xx.xx.xx`

Then hangs for a few seconds until it displays the prompt (`user@host $`) One interesting thing to note: If I press `ctrl+c` during this hang, it immediately solves it and the prompt flashes up so I'm guessing it's a process that is hanging. What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: Check your login files - `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `.login` etc depending on what shell you use.

Comment: I have disabled everything in `.bashrc` as a test and I still get the same problem so I'm not sure

Comment: How about /etc/profile, and other matching files?

Comment: Ahh, thank you! Moving `/etc/profile.d` to a new location (a crude way of disabling everything inside there) it works instantly. So I will have a look through there now and debug it. Would you mind putting this as an answer so I can mark it as accepted? :-)

Comment: Done, with some extra explanation to make it more generally useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is usually because one of the files used by login has some function that takes a long time to return. It will commonly be either in your own home directory, where you should look at

```
 .profile
 .bashrc
 .login
 .kshrc
 .tcshrc
```

If it's none of those, look in /etc for the same files, but usually without the dot:

```
/etc/profile
/etc/bashrc
```

and so on. The culprit will often be something that does a DNS lookup, but it might also be that you have it set to check when you last logged on, and your `utmp`/`wtmp`/`btmp` is very large.

```
ls -lhS /var/log/
```

Comment: But why should such a problem arise with SSH logins but not with local logins?

Comment: It doesn't say anywhere in the question that it doesn't happen with local logins.

Comment: I haven't tried it with local logins. The culprit was `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion`. I moved that and it works perfect. It just runs `/etc/bash_completion` which, when I ran it, took a good few seconds to do whatever it does. Does anyone know if this is vital?

Comment: It's not vital; it's used to build helper functions that will expand and complete the command line for you - e.g. if you type "foo" and press `TAB`, it'll find all programs starting with "foo" for you.

Comment: @andy It's not important (OK, that assessment may differ between individuals...) but nonetheless it should not take that long. You could start it with `bash -vx /etc/bash_completion` in order to see what the problem is.

Comment: @JennyD Completing commands and filenames is built into bash, the bash_completion scripts expand that by being aware of the command you've typed so far and will come up with options to complete it that aren't filenames.  For instance, the git bash_completion scripts will complete `git checkout br[tab]` with branch names instead of file names. `ssh foo@[tab]` reads /etc/hosts to find hostnames, etc.

Comment: @DerfK yes, I should have been clearer with what I meant with "helper functions". Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score -1):

A frequent reason for this is reverse DNS lookup (which is the default). Put `UseDNS no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: That was my first thought, but as it doesn't show up as a delay when doing `ssh -vvv`, and it goes away if the user presses ctrl+c while waiting for the prompt, it's unlikely to be the culprit.